# How to select an item from ListView and see its corresponding id from SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, adapter

I have the following two files:

podatkovna_baza.java

```
package com.example.ultimate.basketball.stats;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class podatkovna_baza extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "baza5";

    public podatkovna_baza(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase baza5) {
        /*
         * Create the employee table and populate it with sample data.
         * In step 6, we will move these hardcoded statements to an XML document.
         */
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ekipe4 (" +
                                        "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                                        "ime_ekipe TEXT, " +
                                        "kratko_ime TEXT, " +
                                        "kraj TEXT, " +
                                        "slika TEXT )";
        baza5.execSQL(sql);

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put("ime_ekipe", "Drustvo partizan");
        values.put("kratko_ime", "DRP");
        values.put("kraj", "Mirna");
        values.put("slika", "jajaja");
        baza5.insert("ekipe4", null, values);
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase baza5, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        baza5.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ekipe4");
        onCreate(baza5);
    }       
}
```

osnovni_meni.java

```
package com.example.ultimate.basketball.stats;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;



public class osnovni_meni extends Activity {
    protected SQLiteDatabase baza5;
    protected Cursor cursor;
    protected ListAdapter adapter;
    protected ListView ekipe_list;
    protected EditText searchtext;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_osnovni_meni);
        baza5 = (new podatkovna_baza(this)).getWritableDatabase();

        //searchtext = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.searchText);
        //searchText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.searchText);
        //employeeList = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.list);
    }


    public void hello(View view) {
        //cursor = baza2.rawQuery("SELECT ime_ekipe, kratko_ime, kraj FROM ekipe2" , null);

        ekipe_list = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.lista);

        cursor = baza5.query("ekipe4", null, null, null, null, null,
                        "_id" + " ASC");

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                        this, 
                        R.layout.ekipe_layout, 
                        cursor, 
                        new String[] {"_id","kratko_ime","kraj"}, 
                        new int[] {R.id.ime_ekipe,R.id.kratko_ime,R.id.kraj});
        ekipe_list.setAdapter(adapter);
        String sadas=adapter.toStr
    }


    public void delete_byID(int id) {
        baza5.delete("ekipe4", "_id"+"="+id, null);
    }


    public void delete_by_ime_ekipe(String ime) {
        baza5.delete("ekipe4", "kraj"+"="+ime, null);
    }


    public int deleteAll() {
        return baza5.delete("ekipe4", null, null);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_osnovni_meni, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }


    public void vibriraj()
    {
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);               
        v.vibrate(30);      
    }


    public void vpisi(View view)
    {   
        ContentValues values1 = new ContentValues();
        //values1.put("_id", "1");
        values1.put("ime_ekipe", "Chicago Bulls");
        values1.put("kratko_ime", "CHI");
        values1.put("kraj", "Chicago");
        baza5.insert("ekipe4", "kratko_ime", values1);
        vibriraj();
    }


    public void vpisi_ekipo(View view)
    {    
        vibriraj();

        EditText novo_ime_ekipe = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.novo_ime_ekipe);
        EditText novo_kratko_ime_ekipe = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.novo_kratko_ime_ekipe);
        EditText novo_kraj_ekipe = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.novo_kraj_ekipe);
        EditText novo_slika_ekipe = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.novo_slika_ekipe);

        ContentValues values1 = new ContentValues();

        values1.put("ime_ekipe", (novo_ime_ekipe.getText()).toString());
        values1.put("kratko_ime", (novo_kratko_ime_ekipe.getText()).toString());
        values1.put("kraj", (novo_kraj_ekipe.getText()).toString());
        values1.put("slika", (novo_slika_ekipe.getText()).toString());
        baza5.insert("ekipe4", "kratko_ime", values1);
        vibriraj();
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_teams);                        
    }
}
```

Now I want to for example delete a row I select (get ID from list and corresponding ID from database) or edit a row. How do I do this? It's pretty easy to delete or edit a SQLite entry if you know the id from a database, but I do not.

Sorry for my English, as you can see, it's not my first language.

Comment: What do you mean, "I do not"? When you query the database and retrieve an entry, the entry contains the _id, doesn't it? With that id, you can delete or update the row in the database.

Comment: I wanna get an id from listview, when i click on an item....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ekipe_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
            // your code here   
            }
        });
```

Here in "position" you get the id of the item you've clicked.
So you need only to convert the id in ListView to the id in database.

Otherwise you will need to create custom adapter instead of `SimpleCursorAdapter`, and override the getView() method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works, now I can get the id of the listview row. How can I now get the id of the database table? They are not the same, when I delete a row in database the one i delete is missing. For example: 0,1,2,4,5,6,7,9 row.....

Comment: Nevermind, I figure id out, I only added the next code inside onItemClick:  TextView ime_ekipe =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ime_ekipe);
                String s = ime_ekipe.getText().toString();
                searchtext.setText(s);

Answer (score 0):

in the select query you have mentioned "SELECT * FROM ANSWER WHERE ID="

But you have to mention as " "SELECT * FROM answer WHERE ID"

Because table name is answer not ANSWER